# Heroku Launching application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

After Lauching the application in heroku I'm getting "We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly." but after reloading it I'm getting my application . and also I'm getting only two pages of my application visible other than that when I click other pages link  I'm getting the same answer

Comment: did you check the output of `heroku logs`? That might give some information. Usually, this happens if a part (or the whole) of your application crashes.

Comment: might be uve not done `heroku rake db:migrate`

Comment: It is perfectly working in engine yard , why not in heroku ??